# Why are nucleic acids negatively charged at physiological pH?

Tags: biochemistry, nucleic-acids

Why do nucleic acids and mononucleotides have a negative charge physiological ph?

Comment: Are you asking about nucleic acids or nucleotides?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Have you tried looking at the structure of a nucleotide?

Comment: http://www.tud.ttu.ee/im/Tonu.Reintamm/shabarova/4.1.html

Answer (score 0):

The phosphate group/s present in the mononucleotide or nucleic acid result in the structure having an overall slightly negative charge.

Positively charged proteins that are also present in the cell such as histones help to keep the negatively charged nucleic acid stable 'in vivo'.